# "The system cannot find the file specified" error when invoking .NET based COM component

Tags: c#, .net, vba, com, com+

We have a VBA Macro calls a .NET based COM Component (Written in .NET 4.0 and registered as Com component)

This was working fine until last Wednesday.  Since then, when this component is created using the `CreateObject` command, users are getting an error saying:

> “The system cannot find the file specified”

We have not made any changes to the component in between, and for some users it is still working fine.

Even trying to create the object from VBS results in the same error. We cannot reproduce this error on our machines. When we try to access the .NET component directly from another .NET application, it works fine.

A couple of possibilities:

- This .NET dll is NOT strongly signed. Could there be any policies activated to prevent invoking this as a COM component?
- Is there something changed in the COM invocation of a .NET component?

Comment: What about permissions? Do the users having the issue have the same permissions as the ones who don't?

Comment: Where is the file located?   Can you use a Window explorer to open and read file from machines that fail?  Were any windows updates done over the weekend?

Comment: Yes, there are no permission changes or differences with other users (AFAIK) as they can see the files read/write in to those folders etc. Also I tried moving the files to a completely different directory and it didn't help either. Not sure about the Windows updates.

Comment: Also I didn't think it was a /Codebase RegAsm issue as pointed out in some other questions as the installation was working fine until recently.

Comment: Are they using a mapped drive and it has been disconnected?

Comment: It is on local C:\ drive and the files exist on the same path

Comment: Could the files already be opened?  Maybe reboot machine and try again.

Comment: Use a tool such as sysinternals' ProcMon, filter on your exe, and your should see what file the system is looking for (and failing).

Comment: Tried running ProcMon as well. The only NAME NOT FOUND errors are related to some registry keys and these errors are same on the machines where it works as well.

Comment: One thing I noticed with ProcMon is that on the machines that were working, it is sending request for CodeBase registry entry etc. However on the ones that are failiing, there is no registry calls for CodeBase.

Comment: Could there be any  restrictions put in place that loads the assembly only from certain places, such as the location of exe etc?